# How do I dynamically create a data object from an API in React Native?

Tags: react-native, object, dynamic

I am adding a feature to a React Native app that will give the current time in different places throughout the world. I'm using timezonedb to fetch the country name, zone name etc. Is it possible to create a data object from the API dynamically instead of manually typing in each country as there are several hundred? This is how I want it to look.

```
  const data = [
    { label: 'Afghanistan Asia/Kabul', value: 0 },
    { label: 'Albania Europe/Tirane', value: 1 },
    { label: 'Algeria Africa/Algiers', value: 2 },
  ];
```

The data will be used for a drop down menu to select from the various countries/time zones.

```
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import TimeZoneDropDown from '../dropdowns/TimeZoneDropDown';


const tzUrl = 'http://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/list-time-zone?key=myKey&format=json';
const TimeZone = () => {

    const [timeZones, setTimeZones] = useState([])
    const [dayOfWeek, setDayOfWeek] = useState('');
    const getTimeZone = async () => {
        await axios.get(tzUrl)
            .then(res => {
                setTimeZones(res.data.zones.map((z) => {
                    return (
                        z.countryCode
                    )
                }))
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getTimeZone();

    }, []);
    return (
<Text>
    {timeZones}
</Text>
)


}


export default TimeZone;
```

Here is an example of the response.

```
{
    "status":"OK",
    "message":"",
    "zones":[
        {
            "countryCode":"AD",
            "countryName":"Andorra",
            "zoneName":"Europe\/Andorra",
            "gmtOffset":7200,
            "timestamp":1464453737
        },
        {
            "countryCode":"AE",
            "countryName":"United Arab Emirates",
            "zoneName":"Asia\/Dubai",
            "gmtOffset":14400,
            "timestamp":1464460937
        },
        {"
            countryCode":"AF",
            "countryName":"Afghanistan",
            "zoneName":"Asia\/Kabul",
            "gmtOffset":16200,
            "timestamp":1464462737
        }
        .
        .
        .
    ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I want to help you out but im having an issue with getting the api to work on [expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/)

Comment: I've updated my question to show an example of the response. I didn't include my key in the fetch request as it is paid and I didn't want to post online. Basically I want to take the countryName and zoneName from above and make those the labels in my data object. I also want to increment the value each time dynamically so I can use all of the zones in the API without typing each one out manually. There are a lot of them so I'm trying to find the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: After you do your fetch request you can modify the zone array to fit your needs

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/nXfbHS5FC

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the api data to fit however you need it to.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const getTimeZone = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(tzUrl);
      const data = res.data.map((z, i) => {
        return {
          label: z.zoneName,
          value: i,
        };
      });
      setTimeZones(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  getTimeZone()
}, []);
```

That would get you  your desired result. If you are using [react native dropdown picker](https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/item-schema) then when a selection is made, the only data you would have about the selection would be a number. To get anything else, you would have to find it in `timeZones`.

An alternative would be to store the zone data as value, have your incrementing logic exist independently:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const getTimeZone = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(tzUrl);
      const data =  res.data.zones.map((z, i) => {          
          return {
            label:z.zoneName,
            value: z,
          };
        });
      setTimeZones(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  getTimeZone()
}, []);
```

If you are using RNDP, you can use schema to tell it that the label should be zoneName and remove the label from the mapping above

```js
 <DropDownPicker
        {...dropdownState}
        schema={{label:'zoneName'}}
        items={timeZones}
        setItems={setTimeZones}
        min={0}
        max={timeZones.length}
        multiple
/>
```

A [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/dwNvhNR_D)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. a lot. I see how this works now. I'm using React Native Element Dropdown so I should be able to make it work.

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/QlwBYTPk8